# Wrong qt moc.exe path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, moc

I'm trying to switch from Qt4.8.6 to Qt5.
I'm using MSVS2010 for my old code in c++/Qt.

I changed all the paths and made other changes for Qt migration.
On recompiling the code I noticed the moc.exe path is still pointing to older version of Qt i.e. Qt 4.8.6.

How do I configure this path to moc.exe to point newer version of Qt?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try updating $QTDIR under path?

Comment: I changed the QDIR path and it worked. Thanks !